# Insert values in database table avoiding duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores 3 values one being the primary key.

```
table_id, site_id, contract_id
```

[image]

Values are sent from a html form, I need to add more values per `site_id`.

If I post values that don't already exist then it's not a problem obviously.

However the form will post the existing values as well

**Example**

```
1, 1, 1;
2, 1, 2;
3, 1, 3;
4, 1, 4;
```

To insert those I currently have to `delete all where site_id = 1;` this is so that I don't have duplicates in the table.

Is there another efficient way to do this? I can make those composite keys to avoid duplicates but I think I will have to handle errors in that way?

Comment: Yes please close it, although the linked question has a solution it was slightly different than mine as my values were duplicate including non-primary keys. But found the solution.

Comment: Used insert ignore. Having created composite keys. But thanks